# How make a UIScrollView Horizontal

Tags: ios, swift3, uiscrollview

I'm working with a UIScrollView where I want to show images, but the problem is that I need those images to be shown horizontally and now they are only shown vertically, how can I change the direction of my UIScrollView, from vertical to horizontal

This is my class where you implemented the UIScrollView:

```
//

//  fastoClass.swift
//  AutoLayout(
//  Created by Barbatos on 5/14/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 Seccion 15. All rights reserved.
//
import UIKit

class fastoClass: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var scrollHorizont: UIScrollView!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
 }

 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

  var constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
  var i = 0
  var previousLeft: UIView? = nil
  var previousRight: UIView? = nil

  let scrollWidth: CGFloat = self.scrollHorizont.frame.size.width / 2.0
  let imageColors = [UIColor.green, UIColor.lightGray, UIColor.blue, UIColor.red]

        for color in imageColors{
          let newImage = UIImageView()
          newImage.backgroundColor = color
          newImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
          var toView : UIView? = nil
          var toAttribute : NSLayoutAttribute?
          let isLeft = (i % 2) == 0
          if isLeft {

                toView = self.scrollHorizont

                toAttribute = NSLayoutAttribute.leading

            } else {

                toView = previousLeft

                toAttribute = NSLayoutAttribute.trailing

            }

            var topView : UIView? = nil

            var topAttribute : NSLayoutAttribute?

            if i < 2 {

                topView = self.scrollHorizont

                topAttribute = NSLayoutAttribute.top

            } else {

                if isLeft {

                    topView = previousLeft

                } else {

                    topView = previousRight

                }

                topAttribute = NSLayoutAttribute.bottom

            }

            let top = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newImage,

                                         attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top,

                                         relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal,

                                         toItem: topView,

                                         attribute: topAttribute!,

                                         multiplier: 1.0,

                                         constant: 0)

            let leading = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newImage,

                                             attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.leading,

                                             relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal,

                                             toItem: toView,

                                             attribute: toAttribute!,

                                             multiplier: 1.0,

                                             constant: 0)

            let width = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newImage,

                                           attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width,

                                           relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal,

                                           toItem: self.scrollHorizont,

                                           attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width,

                                           multiplier: 0.5,

                                           constant: 0)

            let height = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newImage,

                                            attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height,

                                            relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal,

                                            toItem: nil,

                                            attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute,

                                            multiplier: 1.0,

                                            constant: scrollWidth)

            constraints.append(top)

            constraints.append(leading)

            constraints.append(width)

            constraints.append(height)



            self.scrollHorizont.addSubview(newImage)

            i += 1

            if isLeft {

                previousLeft = newImage

            } else {

                previousRight = newImage

            }

        }

        self.scrollHorizont.addConstraints(constraints)

        self.scrollHorizont.layoutSubviews()

        let contentHeight : CGFloat = scrollWidth * (CGFloat(i) / 2.0)

        self.scrollHorizont.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.scrollHorizont.frame.size.width, height: contentHeight)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {

        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()


    }

}
```

Comment: Chain the images horizontally instead of vertically and constrain the leading anchor of the first image to the leading anchor of the scroll view and the trailing anchor of the last image to the trailing anchor of the scroll view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    var constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()

    var i = 0

    var previousLeft: UIView? = nil

    let imageColors = [UIColor.green, UIColor.lightGray, UIColor.blue, UIColor.red]

    for color in imageColors{

        let newImage = UIImageView()

        newImage.backgroundColor = color

        newImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false


        if previousLeft == nil {

            previousLeft = scrollHorizont

        }

        var con:NSLayoutAttribute? = nil

        if previousLeft == self.scrollHorizont {

            con = NSLayoutAttribute.leading

        }
        else {

            con = NSLayoutAttribute.trailing

        }

        self.scrollHorizont.addSubview(newImage)


        let top = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newImage,

                                     attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top,

                                     relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal,

                                     toItem: previousLeft,

                                     attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top,

                                     multiplier: 1.0,

                                     constant: 0)

        let leading = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newImage,

                                         attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.leading,

                                         relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal,

                                         toItem: previousLeft,

                                         attribute: con!,

                                         multiplier: 1.0,

                                         constant: 0)

        let width = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newImage,

                                       attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width,

                                       relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal,

                                       toItem: self.scrollHorizont,

                                       attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width,

                                       multiplier: 1,

                                       constant: 0)

        let height = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newImage,

                                        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height,

                                        relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal,

                                        toItem: self.scrollHorizont,

                                        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height,

                                        multiplier: 1.0,

                                        constant: 0)



        if i == imageColors.count - 1 {

            let tra = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newImage,

                                            attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.trailing,

                                            relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal,

                                            toItem: self.scrollHorizont,

                                            attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.trailing,

                                            multiplier: 1.0,

                                            constant: 0)

            constraints.append(tra)


        }


        constraints.append(top)

        constraints.append(leading)

        constraints.append(width)

        constraints.append(height)

        previousLeft = newImage

        i += 1


    }

    self.scrollHorizont.addConstraints(constraints)

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, and probe with your solution and it works without problems